# Differential equation of second order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Equation is
$\frac{\mathrm d^2f(x)}{\mathrm d x^2}=-c^2f(x).$ 
Solutions are $$f(x)=Ae^{icx} + Be^{-icx}.$$
How are these solutions obtained? What are steps that come inbetween?

Comment: **Hint:** Assume $f(x) = e^{m x}$, now substitute and solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exponential function $\mathrm e^x$ has the amazing property that it is its own derivative, i.e. $y'=y$.

If $k$ is a constant then $y=\mathrm e^{kx}$ has the property that $y'=k\mathrm e^{kx}$, i.e. $y'=ky$.

If the derivative of a function is a multiple of the function then exponentials will be involved.

In your example, you have $y'' = -c^2y$. Let's guess that $y=\mathrm e^{kx}$ and see what happens.

Well, $y'=k\mathrm e^{kx}$ and $y'' = k^2\mathrm e^{kx}$ and so
$$y''=-c^2y \implies k^2\mathrm e^{kx} = -c^2\mathrm e^{kx} 
\implies k^2\mathrm e^{kx} + c^2\mathrm e^{kx} = 0 \implies
(k^2+c^2)\mathrm e^{kx} = 0$$
Since $\mathrm e^{kx} \neq 0$ e have $k^2+c^2=0$, i.e. $k = \pm \mathrm i c$.

Hence $y=\mathrm e^{\mathrm icx}$ and $y=\mathrm e^{-\mathrm icx}$ are solutions to $y'' = -c^2y$. Moreover, since differentiation is linear, any linear combination of these two will also be a solution. The general solution is then
$$y= A\mathrm e^{\mathrm icx}+ B \mathrm e^{\mathrm -icx}$$
where $A$ and $B$ are constants.

This can be cleaned up. Euler's formula and de Moivre's theorem tell us that $\mathrm e^{inx} \equiv \cos(nx)+\mathrm i \sin(nx)$. Hence
\begin{eqnarray*}
A\mathrm e^{\mathrm icx}+ B \mathrm e^{\mathrm -icx} &=&
A(\cos (cx)+\mathrm i \sin(cx)) + B(\cos (cx)-\mathrm i \sin(cx)) \\ \\
&=& (A+B)\cos(cx)+\mathrm i(A-B)\sin(cx) \\ \\
&=& P \cos(cx) + Q \sin(cx)
\end{eqnarray*}

where $P$ and $Q$ are constants used to relabel $A+B$ and $\mathrm i(A-B)$.

Comment: I think calling the integration constants "random" is unfortunate, but otherwise a nice answer!

Comment: @Lovsovs Changed - don't forget to vote ;-)

Comment: Hehe, yeah, you spotted the carrot! (lol, I hope that makes sense)